# RAML support for a resource PATCH (RFC 7396)

Tags: rest, raml

## Problem

I'm trying to describe an API which is supposed to have resources PATCH methods work like described in [RFC 7396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396).
Basically a POST method have a set of properties in it's body, some required some not.
PATCH (by some standards) has **no** fields required - requests body contains only the fields you want to update, additionally the API allows a client to "clean" a field by sending a `null`.

## Example:

```
#%RAML 1.0

title: test

mediaType: [application/json]

types:
  Create:
    type: object
    properties:
      description: string
  Retrieve:
    type: Create
    properties:
      id: string
  Update:
    type: object
    properties:
      description?: nil | string


/resource:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          type: Retrieve[]
  post:
    body:
      type: Create

  /{id}:
    uriParameters:
      id: string
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            type: Retrieve
    patch:
      body:
        type: Update
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            type: Retrieve
```

in the example I have a Update type specified just for that task, because...  Create has a required `description`, Retrieve inherits from Create as it should return all it's fields and the additional `id`, Update can't inherit from Create as RAML does not allow to override a required field with one that is not required.

## Questions:

1. Is there a better way to describe that API?
2. If not is `nil | string` the proper way to go when writing that Update type "from scratch"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think there's a better way. Only thing is, if you have not required properties in both the create and the update, then you could create a base type.
2. Yes, `nil | [type]` is the way to go. You need to be able to "clean" the property by sending null.